# Help With Cross Domain Flash Variables

Tags: actionscript, flash, cross-domain, crossdomain.xml

I have two flash movies `fl_base` and `fl_top`. `fl_base` contains ActionScript that pulls a string variable from a server and parses it out to determine the navigation menu of a site (the headers, subheaders, and the links to where each of those navigation items should point, as illustrated below).

```
Menu 1
--Sub Menu 1.1
--Sub Menu 1.2
Menu 2
-- Sub Menu 2.1
-- Sub Menu 2.2
```

`fl_base determines the order of the menus and submenus as well as the links`

`fl_top` contains the graphical assets of the navigation (buttons, background, etc), and draws the actual UI.

I'm running into an issue where the links (the getURL) will not work if the aforementioned string variable is pulled from a different domain. So, if `fl_base` and `fl_top` reside in *example.com* and the variable is pulled from *test.example.com*, then `fl_top`, while displaying the UI (menus, buttons, colors) will not allow the user to click on the link. I should note that the `getURL` is located in the `fl_top` movie.

We have a `crossdomain.xml` that allows cross-domain access between flash movies.

Can anyone enlighten me why this isn't working and if there is a solution, short of re-writing the flash movies (which has been decided is a no-go by the higher-ups)

**UPDATE**

I should also mention that I am using SWFObject 2.2 to load `fl_base` and that `fl_top` is called via `loadMovie` from `fl_base`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `allowScriptAccess` when embedding to let a swf from another domain do `getURL()`, [these are the actionscript 3 docs](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16494.html), but I think that applies to actionscript 2 aswell.

Comment: I tried that without any luck. I should note that it's using SWFObject to render the movie (although I don't tihnk that should matter). And that fl_base calls fl_top via the loadMovie function.

Comment: My bad. I was using allowScriptAccess = true instead of allowScriptAccess = always. Problem solved! Only took me 6 months :P Don't know why I didn't post this sooner.